# External form within iFrame displays blank on submit

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, joomla

I currently have a payment gateway that requests the users to submit:
[Link to Form](http://womin.org.za/womin_donate/)

I have placed that external link/form within an iFrame here:
[Link to iFrame](http://womin.org.za/donations.html)

The form works and you can test the PayPal option just to view the redirect, but now the problem I have is that within the iFrame, once I submit the form in the iFrame then the page returns a blank screen.

```
<iframe scrolling="no" target="_blank" src="womin_donate/" width="100%" height="1600px" style="overflow: hidden; border: 0;margin-top: -40px;"></iframe>
```

The form is in WordPress and the iFrame is loaded on a Joomla based framework.

Please help if you have a solution or suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your console you will see the following error:

> Refused to display
>   'https://www.paypal.com/za/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=rORoHTqEhssuW6be…&dispatch=5885d80a13c0db1f8e263663d3faee8d64813b57e559a2578463e58274899069'
>   in a frame **because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'**.

This means that Paypal doesn't allow you to use Paypal in an iframe.

You can confirm this by checking the network request in the console:

[image]

As far as I know, there is no workaround for this, but you can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-option) anyway for some insight into this issue.